# Как работает выделения памяти под поколения объектов в куче в C#?

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

Всем доброго времени суток,
Имеется вопрос по части сборки мусора в C#, как я понял память выделяемая под хип зависит от разрядности процесса,
Для 32 - 1.5гб
Для 64 - 8тб
У каждого из 3 поколений объектов в хипе имеются свои ограничения по памяти, и когда память выделяемая под 0 поколение заканчивается, то бишь не удается разместить новый объект, происходит сборка мусора, все выжившие объекты из 0 поколения переходят в поколение 1, первый вопрос - отчего зависит выделяемая память под определенные поколения и в каких диапазонах оно может варьироваться, занимается ли этим исключительно CLR или можно вручную выставить необходимое количество памяти в ручную и что произайдет если нам нужно будет содержать очень большое количество объектов, изменит ли CLR динамически место для каждого поколения?

Далее, у меня есть некоторое противоречие по алгоритму работы GC, как я понял, GC вызывается(во время работы приложения) из-за нехватки памяти в 0 поколении, и если после его очистки ему не хватает памяти то только тогда он переходит к следующему поколению, но с другой стороны, GC при очистке мусора может "запомнить" что например в 1 поколении уже нету места и при следующем заполнении поколения 0 очистит сначала первое 1 а потом уже 0. Вообщем второй вопрос - как это на самом деле работает, да и чем поможет очистка поколения 1 или 2 если нам нужно разместить новый объект в поколении 0?

Comment: Ну это надо исходный код GC смотреть. А вообще что-то я не думаю, что нужно до такой степени в дебри лезть. Вы с практической точки зрения интересуетесь или чисто теория интересна?

Comment: CrazyElf, к собеседованию готовлюсь

Comment: Для собеса достаточно в принципе знать про поколения, что они существуют и в чём их смысл )  И знать основное правило - что GC лучше руками не вызывать, и настраивать его обычно тоже не нужно. Тем более что там от версии к версии могут меняться настройки и детали реализации. Но если кто поведает интересующие вас детали, я тоже с удовольствием почитаю. Хотя, повторюсь, вряд ли это нужно знать для собеса.

Comment: Документацию почитать, не? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals